# How to find number of WorkDays between 2 dates using InfoPath-2010?

Tags: infopath

How can I find the number of WorkingDays by selecting StartDate & EndDate in InfoPath-2010 ? 
(Excluding Saturday & Sunday. Means only WeekDays).

Please specify the Rule or the mehtod.

Answer (score 1):

There is very detailed description of codeless (aka nocode) approach, just with rules:

- Alec Pojidaev's InfoPath Blog
  Stuff published for no reason (cool codeless infopath solutions mostly)
  [Infopath codeless programming (walkthrough) 2](http://alecpojidaev.wordpress.com/2008/12/30/infopath-codeless-programming-walkthrough-2/)

the 2nd sentence of which is:

> Updated: 5 more forms added at the bottom: “work days calculation
>   (excluding weekends and holidays)”

There are more trivial/obvious approaches with the use of code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to Excel Services, these links may be useful to you:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHXX9ZV-74w

http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2011/02/calculate-work-days-exclude-holidays-infopath-2010-sharepoint-2010-excel-services/

Answer (score 0):

If proposted codeless approaches don't appropriate in your case, another approach could be to create custom webservice to do this and call it from InfoPath. I used this method in my case.