# How to find workingdays between start & end dates by considering custom HolidayList?

Tags: infopath, custom-list

I want to count number of business days between Begin & End dates, but for this I have to consider the holidays declared in HolidayList(CustomList) created in SharePoint Site.

How can I write Rule/Customize ?

Comment: You already asked [the same question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54812/how-to-find-number-of-workdays-between-2-dates-using-infopath-2010) and it was answered + this question has no relation whatsoever to Sharepoint, i.e. to this board

Comment: Yes, please just edit your original question if you want to clarify.

Comment: In the previous question which I have asked, in that I was using xml file to read the holidays. But in this case I want to use CustomList for holidays which is created in SharePoint site.

Comment: There is no essential difference. XML file is secondary data source/connection (2DS). Use instead a 2DS to your sharepoint list with holidays. This was really in [my answer to your previous question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/54908/8319)